# REST: Pulling attribute from element

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have this xml output.

```
<Envelope pf:urn="urn:pf:envelope:1234">
  <ib:Item>1</ib:Item>
  <ib:Amount>15</ib:Amount>
  <ib:Location pf:url="http://mypage.com/1234/location" pf:urn="Envelope1234"/>
</Envelope>
```

I have this POJO

```
import javax.xml.bing.annotation.*;

@XmlType(namespace="http://mypage.com/schemas/ib/2")
public class Envelope{
  @XmlElement(name="Item")
  private int item;

  @XmlElement(name="Amount")
  private int amount;
}
```

I need to get the url attribute from the Location element. How would the POJO look like for that?

Comment: `Amount` not `Ammount`

Comment: Oops, my bad! Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I'm not putting an answer up because I don't remember all the Annotation names, but if you make a class `Location` with `@XmlAttribute` over a String field called `url`, and then have an instance of that class in your `Envelope` class, it should work.